# tabular tabularx automatic linebreak (p/m/b doesn't work as expected)

Tags: tables, line-breaking, tabularx, pdfsync

The following snipped should break at the end of the column

```
\begin{table}[hb]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|p{.5\textwidth}|}
        \hline \bfseries Col 1 & \bfseries Col 2\\\hline
        \hline Line with a considerably long text & An other very long line with text that should break at the end of the page \\
        \hline footnotemark\footnotemark[1] & but obviously the text doesn't break as desired \\
        \hline other text & which is very strange but I want it to break! Also notice that the right vertical line is missing! \\
        \hline other text & \parbox{.5\textwidth}{The parbox works as expected but I think the p/m/b should work too. But the vertical space is unexpected} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

but it looks like this instead:

[image]

It should end at \textwith with correct linebreaks inside the cell. 
I'm using the following preamble:

```
% Präambel
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside, 
listof=totoc,                   % Tabellen- und Abbildungsverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis
%bibliography=totoc,            % Literaturverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis aufnehmen
titlepage,                      % Titlepage-Umgebung statt \maketitle
headsepline,                    % horizontale Linie unter Kolumnentitel
%abstracton,                    % Überschrift beim Abstract einschalten, Abstract muss dazu in {abstract}-Umgebung stehen
%DIV11,                         % auskommentieren, um den Seitenspiegel zu vergrößern
BCOR6mm,                        % Bindekorrektur, die den Seitenspiegel um 6mm nach rechts verschiebt,
]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}  % ermöglicht die direkte Eingabe von Umlauten
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % deutsche Trennungsregeln und Übersetzung der festcodierten Überschriften
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Ausgabe aller zeichen in einer T1-Codierung (wichtig für die Ausgabe von Umlauten!)
\usepackage{graphicx}           % Einbinden von Grafiken erlauben
\usepackage{amsmath}            % Mathe Erweiterungen wie z.B. split
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathpazo}           % Einstellung der verwendeten Schriftarten
\usepackage{textcomp}           % zum Einsatz von Eurozeichen u. a. Symbolen
\usepackage{listings}           % Datstellung von Quellcode mit den Umgebungen {lstlisting}, \lstinline und \lstinputlisting
\usepackage{xcolor}             % einfache Verwendung von Farben in nahezu allen Farbmodellen
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}     % zur Erstellung des Abkürzungsberzeichnisses
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % Zusatzpaket zur Gestaltung von Fuß und Kopfzeilen
\usepackage{tocbasic}           %
\usepackage{hyperref}   
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{array}              % Tabellen format
\usepackage{threeparttable}     % Footnote in table
\usepackage{tabularx}           % table stuff
\usepackage{tabulary}           % table stuff
\usepackage{pdfsync}            % Duno what this is for?!
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{paralist}           % compactitem itemize
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=verbose,style=alphabetic,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\setlength{\voffset}{-2cm}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
        andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},            % 'et al.' anstatt 'u.a.'
        editor    = {(Hrsg.)},
        editors   = {(Hrsg.)}} 

% Tabellenformat festlegen
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
```

Comment: Works for me. Please extend your example with your preamble.

Comment: Preamble added; I have to admit that this is shamelessly copied from a template. I don't understand everything in there.

Comment: Phew. Goodness. This won't do. Please edit your preamble down to the minimum which will demonstrate the problem. This way you get a first impression where the conflict lies, and it's much easier to help.

Comment: I agree with @StephanLehmke fully.

Comment: Remove the call to `pdfsync`: it's outdated and, as you realized, can give problems.

Comment: You have `% Duno what this is for?!` in your preamble. This is always a good sign that you probably don't need the package, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for adding your entire preamble. We do not call it a MWE. However,

`\usepackage{pdfsync}` has some conflicts. Hence using

```
\usepackage[novbox]{pdfsync}
```

will solve this issue.