# Automatic adjustment of cell width

Tags: tables

My problem is similar to [tabular tabularx automatic linebreak (p/m/b doesn't work as expected)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49487/tabular-tabularx-automatic-linebreak-p-m-b-doesnt-work-as-expected).

However he had some other issues that I don't have.

I have a two-column article. In this article I have a table with two columns, using the regular `tabular` environment.

The problem is that the second column doesn't automatically do the linebreaks, probably due to the fact that I set the paragraph width to `\textwidth`.
I know I can fix this problem by setting something like `0.35\textwidth`, however, this is something that is really bugging me.

Isn't there an option/parameter that just tells the last column (far right column), for example, to stop at the margin? I might want to adjust the size of the first column manually, but then, in this case, the second column, should just take the remaining space, up to the margin.

Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Here, main documents begins %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\title{FooBar}
\author{Bar Foo,~\IEEEmembership{foobar@google.com}}

% The paper headers
\markboth{FooBar 2013}%
{FooBar2013}

% make the title area
\maketitle

%% -----------------
%% |   Main part   |
%% -----------------

\lipsum

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ r p{\textwidth} }
    & \\
    Step 1: & \lipsum[1] \\
    Step 2: & \lipsum[2] \\
    Step 3: & \lipsum[3] \\
    & \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess you're looking for `tabularx` provided by the package with the same name.

Comment: @egreg Would you mind elaborating a little bit? I couldn't find a way to do it with `tabularx` either.

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ r X}`

Comment: This would probably be better set as a description list that a table (which would allow page breaking and generally be more flexible)

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} r X @{}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list as a table and then as a list, note how the list version breaks into the second column of the page which a `tabular` can not do.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{IEEEtran}

%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Here, main documents begins %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\title{FooBar}
\author{Bar Foo,~\IEEEmembership{foobar@google.com}}

% The paper headers
\markboth{FooBar 2013}%
{FooBar2013}

% make the title area
\maketitle

%% -----------------
%% |   Main part   |
%% -----------------

\lipsum

\section{aaa}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} r X @{}}
    Step 1: & \lipsum[1] \\
    Step 2: & \lipsum[2] \\
    Step 3: & \lipsum[3] \\
\end{tabularx}

\section{bbb}
\begin{description}
\item[Step 1]
 \lipsum[1]
\item[Step 2]
\lipsum[2]
\item[Step 3]
\lipsum[3]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

---

alternative list settings

---

[image]

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@IEEEiedmakelabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
                                \parbox[t][0pt][t]{\itemindent}{\raggedright\normalfont\bfseries #1}}
\makeatother


\begin{description}
```

---

[image]

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@IEEEiedmakelabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
                                \makebox[\linewidth][l]{{\normalfont\bfseries #1}}}
\makeatother


\begin{description}
```

Comment: this doesn't prove your point very well.  the `tabularx` version looks nicer to me than the `description` list ... try a shorter page, and put the list on a second page. (and fix the spacing between `description` label and text.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes the item spacing needs tidying up. I didn't as I wasn't sure if it really wanted to be step 1 2 3 in which case it should be `enumerate` with a custom label, eg `enumerate` package and `\begin{enumerate}[Step 1: ]` or if the real case was distinct text so it wants to be a description, there must be loads of answers on site about list formatting, I just wanted to highlight that it didn't have to be a table/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the `description` option. However that doesn't seem to work, when the label is longer... It will just overlay with the text.

Comment: As I commented to barbara the list item handling in latex  is very flexible, but it depends what you want, eg you can make it always start a new line, or start a new line after long heading or indent everything to the widest heading (if like in thebibliography you tell it the widest) or ...   (the tabular case is even worse in that case as it squeezes up the other column with the long text)

Comment: some alternatives coming up in the answer