# Big Table with line and pagebreaks

Tags: tables, page-breaking, line-breaking, longtable

For a technical documentation (two columns: function name left, description right) I need a way for automatic line and page breaks in a `table` environment in case the descriptions get a bit longer.

I am currently using [`tabulary`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabulary) which I thought worked fine but breaks when the table is longer than one page. I wanted to try out the [`longtable` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) but I can't get it to work:

```
misplaced alignment tab character &
```

And after a `\\` for the next row

```
there is no line here to end.
```

I couldn't find any information on what seems to be the standard way to handle this. There seem to be a bunch of packages ([`tabularx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx), `tabulary`, `longtable`, ...) with more or less overlapping functionalities.

edit:

This is an example for the `longtable` use. Notice how the line expands over the end of the page (It didnt work in my original document, perhaps there are some conflicting packages. nevermind).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
-foobar & preeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeety long string here whic doesnt automatically break when it reaches the end of the current line.
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

If you replace the `\begin{longtable}` with `\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{l J}` the break at the end of the line works, but now longer documents are not possible anymore since page breaks are not handled.

A list description could work I suppose only that I would like for the text to not continue directly below the description text but is indented to the right so that there is space below the description text (like in a table).

Edit2:

I tried the code posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78075/multi-page-with-tabulary) with the following result:

[image: Link to Image]

I did the table itself with `\begin{ltabulary}{LJ}`

Comment: tabularx tabulary and longtable also share an author:-)  You can use a multi-page tabulary here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78075/multi-page-with-tabulary Not sure what other help I can offer given so little information.

Comment: Note that it can not be in a `table` environment if it needs to be multi-page. floats are boxes and never break.

Comment: A two column function description list sounds more like a list than a table (which is much easier to handle over page breaks) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89995/automatic-adjustment-of-cell-width/90003#90003

Comment: I updated my description. Sorry if I caused confusion.

Comment: `l` is like `mbox` and never breaks over a line change `ll` to `lp{5cm}` or whatever width you want,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{lp{5cm}}
-foobar & preeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeety long string here whic doesnt automatically break when it reaches the end of the current line.
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for now. But I still have to adjust the column width manually. Is there no way to do this automatically, like the tabulary package handles this?

Comment: There is a longtable/tabulary merge here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78075/multi-page-with-tabulary

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edit above. I tried the code above but the two columns overlap (see picture).

Comment: you probably want to use `l` not `L` for the first column, or set the parameters to stop ty columns being to small. The columns are not overlapping it's just that the first column is very narrow and `-foobar` doesn't hyphenate so it will stick out